# what WPF method can I use to set some properties on a control's first display?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to store my app window's size/position and state when the user closes the app and set them back when the user thereafter opens the app.

I did this easily using registry keys (is this even the best way to do?), but I'm wondering where I actually should put the code to set those properties.

I need to set them when the window first "appears" I think. But I have several methods that could be used in this case, namely:

- Window.Show()
- Window.Activate()
- Window.ApplyTemplate()
- Window.Arrange()
- Window.ArrangeCore()
- Window.ArrangeOverride()
- Window.BeginInit()
- Window.EndInit()
- Window.Measure()
- Window.MeasureCore()
- Window.MeasureOverride()
- Window.OnApplyTemplate()
- Window.OnInitialized()
- Window.OnRender()
- Window.UpdateLayout()

I'm aware that most of them just are a bad idea (UpdateLayout() will be called waaaaaaay too often for instance). Idealy I'm looking for a method that will only be called once in the window's life so that I don't have to add a flag checking if this is the method's first call.

so which one would be the best in this case? and why?

side question: I put the code to save the values in Window.Close() (I'm overriding the method in my `MyWindow` class), But I could as well have put it in Window.OnClosing() or Window.OnClosed(). Does this make any difference in my case?

side question (bis): I also have to save a datagrid's column order, where should I put both "saving" and "loading" code in this case?

Comment: would it be worthwhile me tackling your side questions in relation to the architecture proposed in my answer below?  I only ask because the answers to the questions would differ for your current architecture, and the one I have suggested - hope that makes sense? =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Choice: I finally ended up putting the code to load the values from the registry in window.Show().

the reason I did this is because of 2 things:

1. I store the state of the window, (minimized/maximized) and the way WPF does it, I need to first set the width/height, then the maximized state (if needed), otherwise it messes up the layout. And if I don't set the width/height first, I loose them when I de-maximize the window thereafter. So I have to do things in this order precisely: Width + height and them state. (Also, this is necessary when working with multiple screens, otherwise you loose the screen you were working on). This means that some of the methods above are impractical (the "measure" ones for instance)
2. adding to this, if I put my code in most of the methods above-mentioned, I'll get a bad looking effect on first display: the window will first appear with its height and width set, in the middle of the screen, and then after a small delay, the window gets maximized.

putting the code in window.Show() managed to solve those 2 issues. I might have had the same result with one or more of the other methods, but I simply got fed-up with trying different configurations and ended up using the first one that gave me entire satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems to me you are treating WPF like you would an old-school WinForms application.  You no longer need to monitor form events to retrieve information from the Forms Properties.  A majority of WPF Control properties are something known as a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

Amonst some of the clever things dependency properties introduce is [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx).

If you then consider writing the application with an [MVVM Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) you will quickly be able to work the following out yourself... =)

In the View<sup>*1</sup>, you can create either Dependency Properties, or standard properties and implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), which hold the Size/Layout/Position/etc.  Then bind the form's properties (in xaml or code) to the View's Properties.  You can then implement any functionality you like for storing/retrieving the defaults and have automatic updates when the form is changed by simply adapting the Get/Set of the properties in the view.

As a quick example on the Windows' Title:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
    <Grid>...</Grid>
</Window>
```

An example implementation of the view:

```
public class SampleView : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;
    public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e);

    private string _Title;
    public string Title {
        get {
            if (_Title == null) {
                _Title = My.Settings.MainWindowTitle;
            }
            return _Title;
        }
        set {
            _Title = value;
            if (!(_Title == My.Settings.MainWindowTitle)) {
                if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
                }
                My.Settings.MainWindowTitle = Title;
                My.Settings.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  Regarding how best to store user preferences, I wouldn't recommend the registry though, it's far from unheard of.  The registry nowadays is packed full of settings that, *in my opinion*, the registry wasn't really designed for.  Consider using [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh(v=VS.100).aspx) set to a user scope.  That will handle most of the subleties of where and how the data is stored/retrieved and provide a nice type safe interface for you.

<sup>*1</sup> I personally prefer to try and bind everything to the ViewModel and have almost totally dumb Views; though I do know there are plenty of valid cases for the Views having code. I wouldn't say the Size/Layout/etc is really a Business Logic Concern and isn't something I've concerned myself with up to now, so this should probably be handled in the View itself.

EDIT 2 - A quick example of User/Application scope settings:

Here is a quick picture of the settings I added to the project:

[image: Settings screenshot]

The following code attempts to use both the application and user scoped settings.
NB: **Application Scope Settings are ReadOnly at runtime**

```
public class SettingsExample
{
    private Form1 frmMain = new Form1();

    public void Main()
    {
        frmMain.BackColor = My.Settings.DefaultBackColour;
    }

    public void UserLoggedIn()
    {
        frmMain.BackColor = My.Settings.UserBackcolour;
    }

    public void UpdateUserBackcolour(System.Drawing.Color newColour)
    {
        My.Settings.UserBackcolour = newColour;
        My.Settings.Save();
    }

    public void UpdateDefaultBackcolour(System.Drawing.Color newColour)
    {
        My.Settings.DefaultBackColour = newColour;
        // Compiler Error
        // This property is read only because it is an application setting
        // Only user settings can be changed at runtime
    }

}
```

Comment: oy, I must say I tend to converge with lukas and find using MVVM in this case overkill. It's much easier and light to to the saving/loading in the MyWindow class's code behind. DataBindings are not without cost, and using them to just update a property and its source once in the app's life seems just too much to me. Plus, in this case, think about what happens in code-behind when the user resizes the window (I want save the window's size) : thousands of read/write in the registry... not the best way to do, I think. +1 for the application settings though, I'll have a look at it :)

Comment: Fair enough @David and glad I could help with the app settings.  I think there's probably plenty of pros and cons with the bindings.  One might argue in the bindings' defense that if the application is light enough to not justify any performance hit of bindings, the application probably won't be big enough to be concerned with the (assumedly small) performance hit thereof. ^^  Plus, it's less patterns introduced.   However, all subjective and ultimately down to you. =)

Comment: I must add also, that I have to do most of my instantiation/property value affectation in code behind, because of legacy code. So in my case, Bindings would actually make things really messy, and I'll definitely avoid them in my code here (though I use them a lot for other purposes where I am free to do what I want). But I was looking for a more general answer hence the lack of detail in my question. I have had a look at the application settings, but don't really understand the way it works. It looks like it's restricted to exec in visual studio. Do you maybe have a code sample?

Comment: Totally understandable, and t'is all too often the case that the existing application dictates the code approach required.  =(  I'll add a quick settings sample for you to my post, 5 mins...

Comment: With regards to the settings sample I just posted, its actually an awful example due to the whole User logging in I did there...(sorry) if you ignore that part, it does show you how to create, use, and in the case of userbackcolour, change/save the settings.

Comment: I finally got around to try the application settings. Great feature here! but I cannot use it :p. In my case I'd end up with hundreds of application settings (I have a lot of windows to manage - I mean, really, A LOT -) and I don't know them all at build time, so I'd have to add the application settings dynamically and this becomes quite wordy... So I'm gonna stick with the registry. I now use them for other purpose though, and am quite happy with them

Comment: If we're talking hundreds or even thousands, another possible route is to ship your app with a local SqlCe database which you can use not just for application and user settings, but perhaps to help manage with state persistence? Glad you got round to trying out App Settings though, even if you can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you forgot about

> Loaded event - occurs when the element
>   is laid out, rendered, and ready for
>   interaction. (Inherited from
>   FrameworkElement.)

There is no one simple answer. Scenario may vary whether it'a child "dialog-like" window (then I would just set the size a line before Show() ), a new instance of the same window or a new instance of the app.

I will argue that UpdateLayout() is a bad idea. Actually, it's a very good idea. For example:

```
private bool m_onStart = true;

public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(MainWindow_LayoutUpdated);
}

void MainWindow_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (m_onStart)
     {
         m_onStart = false;
         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
         {
              //Start App
         }
         );
     }
 }
```

Even if it's called a thousand time per second (which is very unlikely) you won't even notice it and won't hurt the performance.

All in all, you can make a helper method that saves user preference and second the reads it. Since the task is view related and using MVVM and binding is an overkill for this, set the size in Loaded event (do it when all ctors, initialization and visual tree is done).

Comment: "bi[n]ding is overkill for this". I'm not arguing the point, just wondered why?

Comment: because you need set up a lof of stuff to do simple task. That's why MVVM light is doing pretty well. "The second comes from MVVM creator John Gossman himself,[8] who points out that the overhead in implementing MVVM is “overkill” for simple UI operations. He also states that for larger applications, generalizing the View layer becomes more difficult. Moreover, he illustrates that data binding, if not managed well, can result in considerable memory consumption in an application."

Comment: I haven't had a chance to go through MVVM light, so thanks for mentioning it.  Not sure what you mean by "you need to set up a lot of stuff" because comparing our two code samples, there doesn't seem to be much difference in amount of code, and the code I posted doesn't need to maintain (itself) a state - the m_onStart flag.  However, I'll go over the MVVM light articles I can find and work it all out. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Actually, it's all of this: I have a MyWindow class that can be the very first window, or a child window, and one instance can be both in the app's life, depending on the context. Hence my idea of overriding one of the above-mentioned methods to achieve what I want. I'm still not convinced about using LayoutUpdated though. it's called whenever you move the mouse over the window so it's actually called very often and you can reach maybe not thousands but hundreds of call per second. Plus, it's a nightmare to debug. (you can't put breakpoints)